# Unzip to directory of the same name

Tags: command-line, bash, unzip

I am trying to unzip files supplied by Google Takeout and need a command to unzip all zip files in a directory to a directory of the same name as the zip file to avoid conflicts.
The zip names cannot be pre-determined so therefore neither can the resulting unzipped directories.

Eg

```
-zipstore
----zipname1.zip
----zipname2.zip
```

should result in

```
-zipstore
----zipname1.zip
----zipname1
----zipname2.zip
----zipname2
```

Where zipname1 and zipname2 are the directories containing the unzipped files.

A further consideration is how do I detect if the zip has finished downloading before extracting - these are 10Gb files !!

Comment: Depending on how varied your input zips are, https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/317721/524752

Comment: @Datadimension "detect if the zip has finished downloading": Browsers usually download the file as different names (`somemixofsymbols.crdownload`) before renaming it to `.zip`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Extract several zip files, each in a new folder with the same name, via Ubuntu terminal](https://askubuntu.com/questions/518370/extract-several-zip-files-each-in-a-new-folder-with-the-same-name-via-ubuntu-t)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

AFAIK, unzip doesn't support that natively, but it supports specifying an extraction directory name with `-d`.

So, for extracting single archives, you can define your own function making use of the shell's parameter expansion to strip out the extension part i.e. `.zip` in the filename like this:

```bash
myunzip () 
{ 
    unzip "$1" -d "${1%.zip}"
}
```

... and then use it like so:

```
myunzip zipname1.zip
```

or use a shell loop for extracting all archive files in the current working directory at once like so:

```bash
for a in *.zip; do unzip "$a" -d "${a%.zip}"; done
```

However, to constantly monitor a certain download directory and automatically unzip completed zip archive files downloads, you'll need to set a watch on that directory using e.g. [`inotifywait`](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/jammy/man1/inotifywait.1.html) with its `close_write` event (to wait until the archive file has completely downloaded and written to disk). Which you can implement in a script like:

```bash
#!/bin/bash

inotifywait -m -q -e close_write /path/to/dir/ |
  while read -r path action file; do
    if [[ "$file" =~ .*\.zip$ ]]; then
      unzip "$path$file" -d "${path}${file%.zip}"
      fi
  done
```

Comment: testing now, thanks. A further consideration is how do I detect if the zip has finished downloading before extracting - these are 10Gb files !!

Comment: @Datadimension One way is the `close_write` event of `inotifywait` … See examples https://askubuntu.com/a/1443575 and https://askubuntu.com/a/1418903